# Spring batch : In memory meta data - out of memory

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I need to read huge database and write it to another database. I do not want to store meta data in some database but rather in memory. But, I get out of memory exception after sometimes. Is there anyway to clear this meta data or rather disable meta data saving mechanism?

Comment: are you using spring boot underneath?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no option of disabling even the in-memory persistence in spring batch.

Actually meta data can not give out of memory exceptions, as there is only job related metadata that needs to be kept in memory. See if the application is keeping something else in memory in any step, tasklet OR if the chunk size is not proper and try fixing that instead.

If it is spring boot based code, then try these in application.properties file: `spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false` and/or `spring.batch.job.enabled=false`